# Writing to Excel misses some data using Thread

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, kinect

I am using Kinect v2 to record and do some calculation on a subject's skeleton which is a time consuming task. I also write data about the skeleton to an Excel sheet simultaneously which freezes the software. As a result, I used Thread to handle the Excel writing task. It runs smoothly but the problem is that when I write to an Excel sheet, it misses some cells as the picture shows. Any suggestion?

[image]

```
 testThreadStart11 = new ThreadStart(excelwriter);
 testThread11 = new Thread(testThreadStart11) { IsBackground = true };
 testThread11.Start();


 public void excelwriter()
 {
      _excelWorksheet.Cells[_excelCol, 1] = _excelRowNum;
      _excelWorksheet.Cells[_excelCol, 2] = limb1.ToString();
      _excelWorksheet.Cells[_excelCol, 3] = limb2.ToString();
      _excelCol++;
      _excelRowNum++;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the main thread store all the values to a Queue and in only one background thread write values from this Queue to excel

Example Code:

```
    class Data
    {
        public int C1 { get; set; }
        public int C2 { get; set; }
        public int C3 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static Queue<Data> RowsDataQueue = new Queue<Data>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadStart testThreadStart11 = new ThreadStart(excelwriter);
            Thread testThread11 = new Thread(testThreadStart11) { IsBackground = true };
            testThread11.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Data RowData = ReadDataFromSomeWhere();
                RowsDataQueue.Enqueue(RowData);
            }
        }

        public static void excelwriter()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (RowsDataQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    Data D = RowsDataQueue.Dequeue();
                    //write values in the D to the excel file...
                }
            }
        }

        private static Data ReadDataFromSomeWhere()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like you are starting a thread per row, and keeping state in your class.

That won't work without proper thread synchronization. The other threads will modify _excelCol and _excelRowNum while they are running. If you just need this to offload the UI thread, consider just starting a single new thread. Alternatively add proper locking around modifying state.

Comment: I just want to offload the UI as you mentioned. Could you please let me know what should I change?

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly given your very small snippet of code. But, to generalize, if you have the testThread.Start inside a loop, move it outside of the loop. You only want one thread. If you're unsure, try to set a breakpoint at the thread Start(); call.